# Dynamically load xml control and share UI control

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I am new to xamarin. Is it possible to load a shared UI control in an xml file, if yes, how? I am open to better idea.

Below is a static loading via `include`, where `parent.axml` statically load `child.xml`.

```
 <include
            android:id="@+id/child"
            layout="@layout/child"
            android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

parent.axml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <include
        android:id="@+id/child"
        layout="@layout/child"
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/parent_layout"
        android:layout_below="@id/child">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/parent_text"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Click to go to the moon!"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:singleLine="true" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Child.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"> 
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/child_text"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="You made it!"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

The idea is that it can achieve share of UI controls. In this case, parent.axml loads child.xml into its place holder based on condition.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `LayoutInflater` to inflate layouts and auto-attach them to the parent (or not):

```
var linearLayout = LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.Child, parent, true);
var textView = linearLayout.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.child_text);
textView.Text = "Inflated and attached to Parent";
```

Also depending upon your use-case, using a self-contained `Fragment` and adding that to your "parent"  might be better a better solution.

Comment: What do the xml of both parent and child look like using your first suggestion? Because the parent.axml should specify the position of place holder for any xml, rather than statically specifying child.xml.

Comment: Is your second suggestion about using Fragment and Activity?

Comment: @Pingpong `parent` in my example is where you want to attach the inflated layout, this would typically be a `ViewGroup`, ie. a xxxxxLayout container. And yes, use an Activity that include Fragments for those items that are repeating either across multiple Activities or within one Activity.