# Android / C#: Clone a widget?

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

Using C# (Visual Studio for Mac), is it possible to clone widgets that are accessible by ID?

Example:

```
RelativeLayout stage = FindViewById<RelativeLayout>(Resource.Id.proto_rel_layout);
new_stage = stage.Clone(); // <- Functionality I'd like.
```

My app creates a long list of elements that contain several text fields and one image each. Their layout is dreadful at the moment as I've been creating them programmatically in C#.

What I'd like to do, is to use the UI designer (and allow future developers to use it) to decide what each entry should look like, using a RelativeLayout container with a bunch of child widgets. One such entry would be designed in the UI builder with example data, and then for every real entry, this RelativeLayout widget and its children would be cloned, reconfigured according to the input data, and then added to the list. The prototype itself would be hidden somehow, or removed, or could even be recycled as the last entry, but I'm not that far yet because I'm unable to clone it in the first place.

This would make it easier for designers and developers (not to mention myself) to design this part of the UI with the tools intended for that, without the need to manually translate that design into C# code which then is called repeatedly in a for-loop.

I don't care if I have to clone all the widgets or just one of them. It's perfectly fine if the cloning mechanism has to know the ID of every widget in advance. The point is that I'd like a designer to be able to make modifications to the design without a programmer needing to manually translate it into C#.

However, I am unable to find a function that I would expect to clone a widget in this way. There do not appear to exist functions such as .Copy() or .Clone().

I wonder if there is another way, like basing a widget on an already existing one or some other method that I'm not thinking of.

Long story short; is it possible to clone widgets in Android (C#) and if so, how is that achieved?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51126006/dynamically-load-xml-control-and-share-ui-control/51126232#51126232

Answer (score 0):

It is not exactly possible to clone these widgets, unless you do the grunt work yourself. However, as SushiHangover commented in your OP. Instead of thinking about cloning, instead encapsulate whatever UI code in a Layout file and then Inflate it on demand. This way you will get your "clone" in a clean slate when you need it.

This is similar to how RecyclerView and ListView work when they need to create a new row. They inflate a layout that you specify in the Adapter.

I am not sure how many different kinds of Layouts you want to use. However, I would strongly consider using RecyclerView for what you describe and tell the RecyclerView that it contains different types of rows, so it can manage the memory nicely. Especially, if you are going to show more "clones" than can fit on the screen.